# simple-cdd : including custom deb files

Tags: debian, apt, deb

I can create a custom CD with simple-cdd wich install by default severals packages (I want apache and mysql for example), but I have a problem when I want to add custom deb files (first one is nammed siglcode).
I put them in a directory, I add the parameter --local-packages localpackages/ (I put the first error, sorry it's in french but I translate at the end of the line)

```
checking for missing dependencies with edos-debcheck:  /home/cedric/www/EC/SIGL_OS/simplecdd/tmp//mirror/dists/squeeze/main/binary-i386/Packages /home/cedric/www/EC/SIGL_OS/simplecdd/tmp//mirror/dists/squeeze/contrib/binary-i386/Packages /home/cedric/www/EC/SIGL_OS/simplecdd/tmp//mirror/dists/squeeze/non-free/binary-i386/Packages
Merging...                                                          0      Warning: Bad package name: siglcode 
Fatal error: exception Failure("Error: Really bad package name: siglcode 
")
Lecture des listes de paquets... #reading packages list
E: Problem parsing dependency Depends
E: Erreur apparue lors du traitement de siglcode (NewVersion1) #error during siglcode computing
E: Problem with MergeList /home/cedric/www/EC/SIGL_OS/simplecdd/tmp//cd-build/apt//squeeze-i386/apt-state/lists/_home_cedric_www_EC_SIGL%5fOS_simplecdd_tmp__mirror_dists_squeeze_contrib_binary-i386_Packages
```

Here is the file MergeList have a problem with on the last line

```
Package: siglcode
Version: 1
Architecture: all
Depends:
Maintainer: cedric <c.girard@server>
Priority: optional
Section: main
Filename: pool/contrib/s/siglcode/siglcode_1_all.deb
Size: 750
SHA256: d3491aa258eaad14b9987b9e8be669d713d3bc8ca25c2c1945796df381854a56
SHA1: 116187e208d14457671bc991b4a083063fef9f7f
MD5sum: 8b6eef87c90bac1785341d4eb3f56a20
Description: code de l'application
```

I do not undestand where is the problem.

Best regards
Cédric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was building deb files on an Ubuntu 11.04 box, and installing them on a Debian Squeeze : so stupid. Built on a Squeeze now, and no more problem.